# SQL query, field name paseed by reference vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm having problems trying to make this work, I have this query on an application that Im writing in vb.net 2012:

```
Dim strSql As String = " SELECT * FROM Table_Master WHERE  field & "'= ('" & txtCadena.Text & "')"
```

What I need is to have the option to choose the field that I'm querying writing the field name on a textbox.

Comment: You need to be more specific and clarify all of it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would suggest to use a parameter then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
strSql As String = string.format("SELECT * FROM Table_Master WHERE [{0}] = '{1}'", txtField.text, txtFieldValue.text.replace("'","''"))
```

This should work (only for text, not dates, numbers etc) but you have to know that it is not the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it doing this.

```
Dim Query As String 
Dimm DT As DataTable = New DataTable 

Query = "select Actual, Description, Unit_of_measurement from Table_ARTIClES WHERE NUMPART = '" & txtPartNum.Text & "'"

Dim Table As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn)
Table.Fill(DT)

lblInventory.Text = DT.Rows(0)("Actual").ToString
```